# what version of perlin noise does Unity use?

Tags: unity-game-engine, perlin-noise

Fond out that there is not one but 2 versions of Perlin noise as seen [here](https://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/paper445.pdf)

Since the second one is the improved version of the first one, I was wondering witch one Unity3D is currently using as I use it quite a lot and was wondering if I should make my own version of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no such a thing as a *"version"* of perlin noise.

Originally, "Perlin noise" refered to one specific algorithm, developed by *Ken **Perlin***, to generate gradient noise.

Nowadays, the term "perlin noise" is used to describe a wide range of modified and/or tweaked ***implementations*** of the original algorithm.

I don't know what you mean by "first one" and "second one". Your question is malformed.

The question you should probably ask instead is:

> "How is Perlin noise implemented in unity?"